# Maximum area of a bounded rectangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, analytic-geometry, area, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Without calculus, I am trying to find the maximum area of a rectangle that is bounded by the $x$ and $y$ axis and bounded by the line $y=-2x+1$. It is also parallel to both axis.

I would post an attempt but I am lost on how to even get this started...

Updated attempt

Area = $xy$
$$ = x(-2x+1)$$
$$ = -2x^2+ 2x$$

This parabola opens down so it has a maximum at its vertex which is $(1/4, 3/8)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $a,b$ be the coordinates of the rectangle vertex opposite to the origin, then $a, b \ge 0$ and $b=-2a+1$. The area is:

$$a \cdot b = a (1-2a)=-2a^2 + a = -2\left(a-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{8} \le \frac{1}{8}
$$

Comment: I followed up to where you got $-2a^2-a$ What did you do from there?

Comment: @combostudent [Complete the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square): $-2a^2+a=-2\left(a^2-2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot a + \color{red}{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}\right)$ $=-2\left(\left(a-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2-\frac{1}{16}\right)$ $=-2\left(a-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{8}\,$.

Comment: Got it and why is that less than or equal to $1/8$?

Comment: @combostudent Because the square of a real number is always non-negative, so $-2\left(a-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 \le 0\,$ (with equality iff $\,a = \frac{1}{4}\,$). Now add $\,\frac{1}{8}\,$ to both sides of the previous inequality.

Comment: Can I get the vertex of this parabola to find my maximum x value then Plug that in the equation of the line to get the y value ?

Comment: @combostudent The above gives you that the maximum area is $\,\frac{1}{8}\,$, and it is attained for $\,a=\frac{1}{4}$ $\iff b = -2a+1 = \frac{1}{2}\,$.

Answer (score 1):

The area it's $$x(1-2x)$$ and since $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$, we can use AM-GM:
$$x(1-2x)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot2x(1-2x)\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2x+1-2x}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{8}.$$
The equality occurs for $2x=1-2x,$ which says that $\frac{1}{8}$ is a maximal value.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Put one corner at the origin, one on the line $y=-2x+1$.  Call that second corner $(a,b)$.  Express the area in terms of $a$ and $b$, and use the line equation to write $b$ in terms of $a$.

Thus, write the area as a function of $a$ only.  Maximize that function with whatever tools you've got (knowledge of quadratic functions is sufficient).

Comment: I know that the vertex of a parabola is either the max or min. Does that help?

Comment: Sure! Use all your tools for graphing the quadratic function that you get to see what value of $a$ will give you the maximum area. Cheers!